# Unpack dictionary from Pandas Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe that has one of the columns as a dictionary. I want to unpack it into multiple columns (i.e. code, amount are separate columns in the below Raw column format). The following code used to work with pandas v0.22, now (0.23) giving an index error:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.col_name.fillna(pd.Series([{'code':'not applicable'}], index=df.index)).values.tolist())

ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies x
```

I searched google/stack overflow for hours and none of the other solutions previously presented work anymore.

Raw column format:

```
     dict_codes
0   {'code': 'xx', 'amount': '10.00',...
1   {'code': 'yy', 'amount': '20.00'...
2   {'code': 'bb', 'amount': '30.00'...
3   {'code': 'aa', 'amount': '40.00'...
10  {'code': 'zz', 'amount': '50.00'...
11                            NaN
12                            NaN
13                            NaN
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    codes=[
        {'amount': 12, 'code': 'a'},
        {'amount': 19, 'code': 'x'},
        {'amount': 37, 'code': 'm'},
        np.nan,
        np.nan,
        np.nan,
    ]
))

df

                         codes
0  {'amount': 12, 'code': 'a'}
1  {'amount': 19, 'code': 'x'}
2  {'amount': 37, 'code': 'm'}
3                          NaN
4                          NaN
5                          NaN
```

---

### `apply` with `pd.Series`

Make sure to `dropna` first

```
df.codes.dropna().apply(pd.Series)

   amount code
0      12    a
1      19    x
2      37    m
```

---

```
df.drop('codes', 1).assign(**df.codes.dropna().apply(pd.Series))

   amount code
0    12.0    a
1    19.0    x
2    37.0    m
3     NaN  NaN
4     NaN  NaN
5     NaN  NaN
```

---

### `tolist` and `from_records`

Same idea but skip the `apply`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.codes.dropna().tolist())

   amount code
0      12    a
1      19    x
2      37    m
```

---

```
df.drop('codes', 1).assign(**pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.codes.dropna().tolist()))

   amount code
0    12.0    a
1    19.0    x
2    37.0    m
3     NaN  NaN
4     NaN  NaN
5     NaN  NaN
```

Comment: The challenge here is that .dropna() versions basically reset index which means that I loose any positional aspects. My scenario involves concatenating this column with a different one, based on index.

Comment: `dropna` does **not** reset the index.  It only augments the positions.  You can `reindex` with the original index to get back where you were.  I indirectly reindexed via the `assign` method.

Comment: dropna().tolist() takes out the index for the items as far as I can tell. Can you please detail how I can use reindex to, for example, add back the NaN's in their place? (in your example if NaNs are interspersed - 1 row NaN and 1 Row of actual items) @piRSquared

Comment: @DBa `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df.codes.dropna().to_dict(), orient='index').reindex(df.index)`

Comment: Or based on your initial solution: `df.drop('codes', 1).assign(**pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.codes.dropna().tolist(), index = df.codes.dropna().index))` . Thanks, I'll add this as the solution!

Answer (score 5):

***Setup***

```
                        codes
0  {'amount': 12, 'code': 10}
1    {'amount': 3, 'code': 3}
```

**`apply`** with **`pd.Series`**

```
df.codes.apply(pd.Series)

   amount  code
0      12    10
1       3     3
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but gives warning: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)   (I believe that's why I didn't use in the first place, although warning was different in previous pandas version)