# Accessing dictionary within Dataframes

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe (with 1324 rows):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2SBa.png)

I need to figure out which cities are good for Take-out ('Take_out': True in attribute dictionary)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do not post images of data or code - give the text. Also, please remember that questions should have a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

To get at this answer I first created a dummy DataFrame for testing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# create a dictionary list
d = list({'Take-out': True} for x in np.arange(10))
ddf = pd.Series(d, name='attributes')
ddf = pd.DataFrame(ddf)
ddf.index.name = 'cities'
print(ddf)
```

This gives a DataFrame similar as in your image.

Next, iterate over the DataFrame, accessing the 'attributes' column like so:

```
# cities buffer will hold successes
cities = []
# iterate over the list of dictionaries:
for i, each in enumerate(ddf['attributes']):
    # check if the keys is in that dictionary, if so, keep the city name
    if 'Take-out' in ddf['attributes'][i].keys():
        # the index is named 'cities' and each position is a city name, so:
        cities.append(ddf.index[i])
print(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries aren't really what you want to be storing in a `DataFrame` but you can try:

```
df = df.assign(**df.attributes.dropna().apply(pd.Series))
df[df["Take_out"] == True]
```

This is more or less the same idea as described here: [Unpack dictionary from Pandas Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512188/unpack-dictionary-from-pandas-column). After unpacking that dict we can just select the rows with "Take_out" == True like you normally do.