# Remove nested JSON from DataFrame without creating new rows or duplicate data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, data-science

**OVERVIEW**

Using `pandas.json_normalize` I was able to normalize JSON data that was output from BigQuery that had several nested objects into a dataframe. The csv representation is below. You'll notice on things like "device" it broke out as it should. In other instances, such as the column and `event_params` it did not. I played around and was able to expand out this object but it would introduce new roles, fortunately, I only need a single key/value depending on the `event_name` value. For this example, I want to extract `session_user_id` and normalize that into a similar wide column layout.

**CSV DATA**

```
event_date,event_timestamp,event_name,event_params,device.operating_system  device.operating_system_version
20200105,69996099900,session_start,[{'key': 'ga_session_number', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '3', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_engaged', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'engaged_session_event', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_id', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '123456789', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': {'string_value': 'auto', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}],IOS,9.3.5
```

**QUESTION**

I might just be in overwhelm, but is there a simple way to extract a single (or easier, all of the keys) with the associate values into additional columns?

For example, new columns would be:

*(Honestly, the naming for key/value is less of an issue as long as its a wide csv flat-file)*

```
event_params.1.key = session_engaged
event_params.1.string_value = None
event_params.1.int_value = 1
[...]

event_params.2.key = session_id
event_params.2.string_value = None
event_params.2.int_value = 123456789
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer, whilst not being very elegant and probably needing a little bit of work to get exactly what you want, is a reasonable start.

## Set-up Data

I've taken your example data and modified the format slightly, to load it into a `dataframe`.

```
columns = 'event_date event_timestamp event_name event_params device.operating_system device.operating_system_version'.split()
data = [
        20200105,
        69996099900,
        'session_start',
        [{'key': 'ga_session_number', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '3', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_engaged', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'engaged_session_event', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_id', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '123456789', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': {'string_value': 'auto', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}],
        'IOS',
        '9.3.5',
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=columns)
```

Initial data:

```
   event_date  event_timestamp     event_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            event_params device.operating_system device.operating_system_version
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start  [{'key': 'ga_session_number', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '3', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_engaged', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'engaged_session_event', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '1', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'session_id', 'value': {'string_value': None, 'int_value': '123456789', 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}, {'key': 'firebase_event_origin', 'value': {'string_value': 'auto', 'int_value': None, 'float_value': None, 'double_value': None}}]                     IOS                           9.3.5
```

## Solution

```
new_df = df.explode('event_params').event_params.apply(pd.Series).value.apply(pd.Series)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('event_params', axis=1), new_df], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   event_date  event_timestamp     event_name device.operating_system device.operating_system_version string_value  int_value float_value double_value
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start                     IOS                           9.3.5         None          3        None         None
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start                     IOS                           9.3.5         None          1        None         None
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start                     IOS                           9.3.5         None          1        None         None
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start                     IOS                           9.3.5         None  123456789        None         None
0    20200105      69996099900  session_start                     IOS                           9.3.5         auto       None        None         None
```

## Explanation

I'll break the description of the first line into multiple steps:

1. Use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) simply to access the inside of the list in `event_params` (you could `apply` a lambda function, if preferred).
2. Use `apply.(pd.Series)` first to expand the JSON [see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512188/unpack-dictionary-from-pandas-column).
3. Use `apply.(pd.Series)` again to expand the `values` column.

Of course the second line just concatenates the two dataframes together, with `event_params` dropped from the original data.

Comment: Thank you, my concern with this method is it creates new rows and therefore duplicate records for some columns — Though might be enough to get me started, as you suggested.

I'm just not 100% on breaking it out into a single flat structure with the same number of rows

Comment: I'm unable to spend more time on this at the moment but have a look at the `pivot` and `pivot_table` methods for padas dataframes.