# Pandas Datafarme : division of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can you help me please.

My Pandas Dataframe has a column that contains dictionaries with information, I want to divide it into several columns where each contains specific information by dictionary key.

original:

```
df.loc[df.index[3],'Information'] = Name:Monika/ Age:21/ City:France/ Job:Doctor/ Date of Birth:1999-04-12
```

expected:

```
df.loc[df.index[3],'Name']=Monika
df.loc[df.index[3],'Age']=21
df.loc[df.index[3],'City']=France
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is unpacking dictionary from Pandas Column.
Please check out this solution: [Unpack dictionary from Pandas Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512188/unpack-dictionary-from-pandas-column)

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, please consider leaving a comment or casting a close vote instead of an answer.

Comment: Point taken. Thank you!