# Sorting of pattern of string values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe which contains rows of  string of several dictionary like values.

**Sample output:**

```
"{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'classy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': False}"
```

I will want to use the str.split method to split each of the different attributes into its own columns later. However, the problem now is that not all of the rows in the dataframe will follow this particular sequence of romantic to casual.Some might have sequences where for example intimate is the first attribute while the last attribute is upscale instead of casual like in the sample output. Point I am making is that there is no consistent pattern throughout the entire data in the way that it is structured. Is it possible to sort like the values all alphabetically for example so that we get consistent value patterns throughout the entire df?

**Sample data:**

```
{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': True, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': True, 'casual': False}

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}

None

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}

None

None

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'classy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': False}

{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': False}

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}

None

None

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}

{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': True, 'casual': True}
```

**Expected output:**

```
{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': True, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': True, 'casual': False}

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}

{'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'classy': False, 'hipster': False, 'divey': False, 'touristy': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'casual': True}
```

Basically the order of the attributes should be romantic,intimate,classy,hipster,divey,touristy,trendy,upscale,casual for all the rows of data which it is not currently.

Comment: can you share a few rows of data from your dataframe? use df.head(20) to get the first 20 rows

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far to get this problem solved? Please share input data, your code, and expected output

Comment: I see the sample data. What are you expecting as output for this data?

Comment: yup just edited

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unpack dictionary from Pandas Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512188/unpack-dictionary-from-pandas-column)  piRSquared has answered it perfectly.

Comment: Based on what you have shared, it looks like you want to rearrange the dictionary to a specific format. You want all rows to be consistent with the `Expected output` format. If a value is not part of the key, should it be set to False by default?

Comment: For example `{'touristy': False, 'hipster': False, 'romantic': False, 'intimate': False, 'trendy': False, 'upscale': False, 'classy': False, 'casual': False}` is missing `'divey'`. Should this be set to `'divey' : False` and included into the dictionary. Then reformatted to align with `Expected output` format?

Comment: What if the row has a value of `None`, should the result of that be `None` as a record or should the record be converted to have `False` for each item in the dictionary?

Comment: If you edit the question and open it up, I can share my answer. For now: dict_keys = ['romantic','intimate','classy','hipster','divey','touristy','trendy','upscale','casual']

Comment: for d in dict_rows:
    if d != None:
        temp_dict = {k:d[k] if k in d else False for k in dict_keys}
        print (temp_dict)
    else:
        print (None)

Comment: Yeah if the row has value of None, just leave it as none as a record